# Event trigger on "ENTER" key press

Tags: vb.net

I have designed a Window_Form in which I want to give a functionality such that whenever a user press "Enter" Button in ComboBox, a query is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Combobox_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Combobox.KeyDown

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

            MsgBox("Here you can execute query")

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Will it be okay If I insert two queries without message box?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void txtShNumber_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter && txtShNumber.Text.Trim() != "")
    {
          /////your code
    }
}
```

it will work for wpf and C# applications